# Replace substring from the listbox (WindowsForms)

Tags: c#, listbox

I have attached in my listbox ( lb1 ) a character to the previous item. The letter A is seperated by a comma. Is it even possible to replace the letter in this line 
(A --> B)? How can this be solved? The result in the listbox( lb2 ) should look as shown below.

```
if (listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Contains("someText"))
{
    int a = listBox1.Items.IndexOf("someText");
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(a);
    listBox1.Items.Insert(a, "newText");
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should know what it should be before creating the items, where is this happening at? Looking at your previous questions, it seems this *could* be done.

Comment: Thank you for pointig that out, „Çöđěxěŕ“

According to listview i wrote the following code (works quite fine): foreach(ListViewItem s in listView1.Items)
     {
     if (s.SubItems[0].Text.Contains("JOHN") &&(s.SubItems[1].Text.Contains("A")))
       {
         s.SubItems[1].Text = s.SubItems[1].Text.Replace("A","B"); 
       }
      }
Unfortunately i did not succed in developing a code for the listbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snippet for your new problem mikee:

You need to iterate through the items of the list box, search for a match, and replace the detected matches:

```
string search = "A";
string replace = "B";

for(int i = 0; i < lb1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if(lb1.Items[i].ToString().EndsWith(search))
    {
        string item = lb1.Items[i].ToString().Replace(search, replace);
        lb1.Items[i] = item;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Please note that, the preceding snippet will change all the **A** characters in the string with **B** not only the last one. So if you have a list item say **JONATHAN, A**, the preceding code will change it to **JONBTHBN, B**. To avoid that you could do:

**Solution 1:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < lb1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (lb1.Items[i].ToString().EndsWith(search))
    {
        int indx = lb1.Items[i].ToString().LastIndexOf(search);
        string item = lb1.Items[i].ToString().Substring(0, indx) + replace;
        lb1.Items[i] = item;
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

If all of your list items are comma separated strings like the image above, then you could do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lb1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (lb1.Items[i].ToString().EndsWith(search))
    {
        var arr = lb1.Items[i].ToString().Split(',');
        arr[arr.Length - 1] = replace;

        lb1.Items[i] = string.Join(", ", arr);
    }
}
```

Sorry for any inconvenience mikee.

Good luck.

Comment: The solution of one problem is a new problem ; ) The code snippet is beautiful and clear! Thank you very much for your support and your help, "JQSOFT"!!

Comment: Anytime mikee. Keep it up.

Comment: Excellent!!! Thank you for your time and your interesting and detailed answers, JQSOFT!!!